# alert command does not change item label color

Tags: overlays, presentations

I use **scrartcl** and **overlays** for creating presentation.
\alert command given in overlays does not change item label color.

> 1.How to change label color into red in the below MWE?
>
> 2.Is there any other better way to achieve it?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt,landscape,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[paperwidth=128mm, paperheight=96mm, margin=8mm, footskip=6mm] {geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{overlays}
\begin{document}

\begin{overlays}{2}
Given four choices, select the correct choice 
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task choice one
\task choice two
\task \alert{2}{choice three}
\task choice four
\end{tasks}
\end{overlays}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to set a label color for the `tasks` environment, and modify the color definition from within `\alert`. To do this you can redefine the `\alert` command, i.e., copy the original definition from the `overlays` package and add the color commands.

The idea is to add a command that does two things: first, set the color, and second, redefines itself in such a way that the next time it is called (by the next `\task` command) the color will be switched back.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt,landscape,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[paperwidth=128mm, paperheight=96mm, margin=8mm, footskip=6mm] {geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{overlays}
% makeatletter/makeatother needed because the definition of \alert uses the @ (at) symbol
\makeatletter
% original definition copied from overlays.sty
\renewcommand{\alert}[2]{\overl@y{#1}{%
     {\color{alert}%
     % added color command below
     % set to red, then redefine the command to set to black
     \gdef\tasklabelcolor{\color{red}\gdef\tasklabelcolor{\color{black}}}%
     % rest of original definition below
     \psset@lertcolor
     {#2}%
     \ifvmode
        \unskip % undo spurious space introduced by \color
     \fi}}{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
% set initial task label color at the start of the document
\def\tasklabelcolor{\color{black}}
\begin{overlays}{2}
Given four choices, select the correct choice
% use color in label definition
\begin{tasks}[label-format=\tasklabelcolor](2)
\task choice one
\task choice two
\task \alert{2}{choice three}
\task choice four
\end{tasks}
\end{overlays}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]